# Omnicomplete with function definitions from documentation

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

How do I go about showing the description of functions in Vim when using Omnicomplete for Python?

Comment: I think rope-vim does what you want https://bitbucket.org/agr/ropevim

Comment: Thanks for the lead, however, am trying to get it to show the function signature for several languages, perhaps by the usage of Doxygen tags..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin (python-mode) which does the abovementioned, including references, etc. It does not have any dependencies and features a documentation window, and runtime button as well.  Link here: https://github.com/klen/python-mode

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It is working just out of the box :)

All you need to have:

- vim compiled with `+python` option. 
  You can check it with `vim --version`. If you are working on Linux, most distributions have this options enabled by default in their packages, or supply enhanced version of vim package (vim-ext, exvim...).
  If you are working on Windows, and then you can download [cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) which is *"A modern configuration of the powerful and famous Vim, "*. It is bundled with vim compiled with interesting options, like `+python`
- then simply open your .py file and type  `C-x C-o` (C is **control**) when you are in the middle of the word.
  Popup will be triggered and new buffer window will be opend with documentation of the selected completition.

```py
import sys
sys.ver|      # | is a cursor position, press here C-x C-o
```

You should get completitions for `version` and `version_info`
[image: omnicompletition image snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply..  Combined this with https://github.com/ervandew/supertab to get tab-based autocomplete working in vim.  However, how would I get omnicomplete to prompt the required function parameters (similar to how it would show on an IDE)  as well?

Comment: Like for example, some prompt which shows the Doxygen tags for that function, like in VCC or Actionscript, for a few languages including Python and Cpp.

Comment: try to extend dictionary completion.
So if you have some list of available compeltions for python you can add it:
`autocmd FileType python setlocal autoindent smarttab complete+=path_to_dict`
More http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1257

Comment: Thanks!  I will try that out.  I found an answer in the form of python-mode

Comment: The question was about omnicomplete, not python mode for vim ;)
I suggest to change the question.